# Import issues when importing stuff from package root's __init__.py

Tags: python, python-3.x, import, module

I think I'm misunderstanding something about the way the import system works when you throw `__init__.py` into the mix.  Here's my (very streamlined for this example) layout (Python 3.5):

```
adminproj/
  __init.__py
  main.py
  functions/
    password.py
```

In `adminproj.__init__.py`, I've defined two components with the intention of using them globally (in main.py and functions.password.py):

```
with open((os.path.dirname(__file__)) + "/config/dev.yml", 'r') as ymlfile:
    config = yaml.load(ymlfile)

logger = logging.getLogger("adminproj")
# followed by a bunch of log customization
```

Now in my scripts, both main.py and password.py, I can do this:

```
from adminproj import config
from adminproj import logger
logger.info("config values: " + str(config))
```

Horray!

But I also want to make my function calls not require fully qualified module names, by adding this into `adminproj.__init__.py`:

```
from adminproj.functions.password import *
```

Now when I do this, everything blows to hell, specifically I get problems with importing "logger" and "config":

```
>>> import adminproj
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/admin/sandbox/adminproj/adminproj/__init__.py", line 12, in <module>
    from adminproj.functions.password import *
  File "/admin/sandbox/adminproj/adminproj/functions/password.py", line 3, in <module>
    from adminproj import logger
ImportError: cannot import name 'logger'
```

I'm pretty sure it has something to do with a name collision or something, e.g. when `__init__.py` imports something which itself imports something that `__init__.py` declares.  Even if that's the right frame of mind, I can't seem to figure out a solution to do what I want to do.  Perhaps using `__init__.py` as a global namespace is in bad form.

The simple solution is to just forget `from functions.password import *` and use fully qualified imports.  But I want to make my function calls short and sweet, yet still utilize the global variables in `__init__.py`.

```
adminproj.contains_profanity("badword")
```

versus.

```
adminproj.functions.password.contains_profanity("badword")
```

Comment: You have a circular import problem. Your modules import each other, and each one assumes the other will finish setting up first. Getting this right will require careful thought about which parts of your code get to rely on which other parts, and you'll likely have to use qualified names instead of `from` imports in a few places you'd rather not.

Comment: You're creating a circular import. `adminproj` depdends on `password.*`, but `password` also needs `adminproj` (for `logger`). One strategy to solving this is to isolate the thing that's needed in several places and extract it into its own module. In your case, you could create `adminproj/logger.py` and `adminproj/config.py` modules and import (from) those where needed.